# Python function doesn't get called I have tried debugger and print statements

Tags: python, tkinter

I think it has something to do with the self object. I have tried print statements and the debugger and I haven't been able to find a solution. This is a simple Python GUI that will soon be starting a timer and stuff but I haven't quite gotten there yet. 
Here's the code: https://pastebin.com/QcAe8bEN

The function that isn't being called

```
 def beginDefault(self):
    initialTime = time.time()
    print("Hello World!")
```

The line where the button is created. Note that the function should be called when the button is clicked.

```
defaultButton = Button(createIntervalFrame, text="Default", command=self.beginDefault and createIntervalFrame.destroy)
```

Initial object is created here:

```
root = Tk()   # creating a blank window
interactive = WellRested(root) # Creates a Well Rested object
```

Comment: I don't see a function call there.

Comment: Sorry that's where the button is created in tkinter. I'll edit the main post but the function is called when the user clicks the button. Thats the command=self.beginDefault part.

Comment: You don't have `command=self.beginDefault`, you have `command = self.beginDefault and createIntervalFrame.destroy`. That is, first the program evaluates `self.beginDefault and createIntervalFrame.destroy`. The `and` operator first evaluates its left operand, `self.beginDefault`, which is a function, which is a true value. So `and` then evaluates and returns its right operand, `createIntervalFrame.destroy`. This value is then passed as `command`. It's as if you'd done `f = self.beginDefault and createIntervalFrame.destroy; defaultButton = Button(..., command = f)`.

Comment: ... because `self.beginDefault and createIntervalFrame.destroy` evaluates to `createIntervalFrame.destroy`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`and` is a logical operator, you can't use it to call several functions. To do what you want you will need a third function which calls the first two:

```
def button_clicked(self):
    self.beginDefault()
    self.createIntervalFrame.destroy()
...
defaultButton = Button(createIntervalFrame, text="Default", command=self.button_clicked)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I’m on mobile right now so I’ll try to mark everything ASAP. Do you know why the function isn’t called but the frame is still destroyed? It’s like it skips the first part and the AND and just destroys the window on click.

Comment: Since a function coerces to True, using the `and` operator on two functions (which should never happen) always results in the second function. So the command argument gets whatever the second function is.

Comment: The other function I made doesn't recognize the createIntervalFrame because it's local to the other function. How can I get around this?

Comment: @pythonhelpthrow make it an instance variable by adding `self.` to the name.